# Consolidate several Oracle triggers. Any performance impact?

Tags: performance, oracle, triggers, oracle11g

Most of our tables have one `BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE` trigger, in order to set ID's `BEFORE INSERT` and to set creation / modification users / dates `BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE`.

There are a couple of tables with additional triggers, which were separated from the previous one in order to make their intent more clear. Also, those additional triggers could be disabled independently from the previous one, which should never be disabled.

In most cases, the additional triggers also fire `BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE` and the order is unimportant, as they cover different columns / use-cases. So generally, they *could* be combined to single triggers.

Are there any studies about the speed of calling `1` or `n` triggers on a table? Or is that pretty much irrelevant for single-row inserts / updates? In other words, is there only 1 global `SQL -> PL/SQL` context switch, or will there be 1 context switch per trigger.

Comment: I suspect the best answer would be for you to test the two options and see if one is consistently faster.

Comment: @JeffreyKemp: Yes, but before I make those tests, maybe someone has already benchmarked these things...

Comment: @JeffreyKemp: See my answer for the benchmark tests. There seems to be no difference in Oracle 11g

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have now benchmarked this situation and I came to the conclusion that there is a significant performance loss most likely due to PL/SQL context switches, when adding 1 trigger. The loss is by factor 8 in my benchmark. Adding a second "compatible" trigger, however, doesn't have any significant impact anymore. By "compatible", I mean both triggers always fire at the same event in any order.

So I'm concluding that there is most likely only 1 `SQL -> PL/SQL` context switch for all triggers

---

Here's the benchmark:

#### Create a table

```
-- A typical table with primary key, creation/modification user/date, and 
-- other data columns
CREATE TABLE test(
  id number(38)    not null, -- pk
  uc varchar2(400) not null, -- creation user
  dc date          not null, -- creation date
  um varchar2(400),          -- modification user
  dm date,                   -- modification date
  data number(38)
);
```

#### ... and a sequence

```
CREATE SEQUENCE s_test;
```

#### A typical trigger setting ID, creation/modification user/date

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER t_test BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
  ON test
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF inserting THEN
    SELECT s_test.nextval INTO :new.id FROM dual;

    :new.uc := USER;
    :new.dc := SYSDATE;
    :new.um := NULL;
    :new.dm := NULL;
  END IF;
  IF updating THEN
    :new.um := USER;
    :new.dm := SYSDATE;
    :new.uc := :old.uc;
    :new.dc := :old.dc;
  END IF;
END t_test;
```

#### Insert 1000, 10000, 100000 Records

```
declare
  procedure run (limit number) is
    t timestamp;
  begin
    t := systimestamp;

    insert into test (data)
    select level from dual connect by level < limit;

    dbms_output.put_line(to_char(systimestamp - t));

    rollback;
  end;
begin
  run(1000);
  run(10000);
  run(100000);
end;
```

#### Results

```
-- ------------------------------------
-- +000000000 00:00:00.086603000
-- +000000000 00:00:00.844333000
-- +000000000 00:00:08.429186000
-- ------------------------------------
```

#### Another "compatible" trigger (execution order irrelevant)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER t_test_other BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
  ON test
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  :new.data := 42;
END t_test_other;
```

#### Results of another run of the test script

```
-- ------------------------------------
-- +000000000 00:00:00.088551000
-- +000000000 00:00:00.876028000
-- +000000000 00:00:08.731345000
-- ------------------------------------
```

#### Deactivate triggers

```
alter trigger t_test disable;
alter trigger t_test_other disable;
```

#### Run a slightly different test script

```
declare
  procedure run (limit number) is
    t timestamp;
  begin
    t := systimestamp;

    insert into test (id, uc, dc, data)
    select s_test.nextval, user, sysdate, level from dual 
    connect by level < limit;

    dbms_output.put_line(to_char(systimestamp - t));

    rollback;
  end;
begin
  run(1000);
  run(10000);
  run(100000);
end;
```

#### Results

```
-- ------------------------------------
-- +000000000 00:00:00.012712000
-- +000000000 00:00:00.104903000
-- +000000000 00:00:01.043984000
-- ------------------------------------
```

Comment: I'm not sure this test is very reliable. I would compare two identical tables; one with 1 trigger that does 10 actions, the other table with 10 triggers that do each of those same 10 actions. The difference between performance of 2 vs. 1 trigger is probably too small to rise above the noise.

Comment: @JeffreyKemp: That would be a good thing to test. In my case, however, I merely wanted to know whether 2 triggers take ~2x as long to execute as 1 trigger, which does not seem to be the case....

Answer (score 1):

I know there's a significant difference in redo generation between no triggers and a single trigger, but not about a difference between 1 and n triggers.  However, I can't imagine there isnt a hit, as there would be more context switching between the SQL and PL/SQL engines.

Comment: Hmm, in essence, I'm wondering if there are really multiple context switches, or just a single one. In principle, some optimisation could be applied in order to switch contexts only once

Comment: I now did the benchmarking and found no difference between inserting into tables with 1 or 2 triggers. See my answer for details

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you investigate the impact of using the Sequence in the trigger - when creating the sequence seed the sequence with a cache value
(CACHE specifies how many values of the sequence the database preallocates and keeps in memory for faster access).   I have experienced factors far greater the 8 associated with sequences.  In any case, in order to compare the impact of a trigger in the terms of context switching the use of the Sequence should be either eliminated for the test or taken into consideration when evaluating the results.

Comment: Interesting. I hadn't thought about the possibility of the sequence being the problem here...