# Multiple small trigger vs single large trigger on table

Tags: oracle, triggers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Consolidate several Oracle triggers. Any performance impact?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8579240/consolidate-several-oracle-triggers-any-performance-impact)

**Question:**
Which one is best (for performance)? Having **multiple triggers** (about 7-10) one for each situation/purpose, or **one trigger** which handles all the situations (by using if, etc).

**Detail:**
We're developing enterprise application based on **Oracle database**. We have one table with approximately 3M rows, which is base table for our app. And there are several situations that we need to handle only with triggers. IMHO, for maintenance, it's better to have multiple triggers. But what about performance?

Comment: Do you realize that if you have multiple triggers of the same type on a single table, then Oracle Database chooses an _arbitrary_ order to execute these triggers. Each subsequent trigger sees the changes made by the previously fired triggers. Each trigger can see the old and new values. But as stated, the execution order is arbitrary. To ensure that multiple triggered actions occur in a specific order, you must consolidate these actions into a single trigger.

Comment: Yes, I realize (and know) that. This situation is like, one trigger insert into `table_1`, second one updates `table_2`, third one insert into `table_3` (of course with their little logic). All the triggers doesn't have any order (or relation). We can put them into one big trigger, or separate as multiple triggers.<br/>
Maybe someone will tell us that we shouldn't do it by triggers. But this is special situation and this question is about understanding the database (behind the scene process).

Comment: This could be of interrest : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8579240/consolidate-several-oracle-triggers-any-performance-impact

Comment: Yes, that was useful. Thanks.

Comment: If you're seriously considering 7-10 triggers isn't it wise to consider putting everything in a package instead?

Answer (score 0):

In my case one single trigger was much quicker than multiple small triggers. Why I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see how multiple triggers would perform noticably faster.  the only trade-off is they would not execute the conditional logic, saving very small fractions of a second.

This is really a design/maintenance question ...  Let's say, you want to instrument the code to give you timing information: if you have one trigger, then you only need to go into one program, whereas with multiple triggers, you need to go to multiple places to instrument the code.

Also, consider using CASE statement instead of IF (It's a lot cleaner/easier to read/maintain).